# Cannot see Javascript functions or variables in Structure window in IntelliJ Community edition

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I cannot see Javascript functions or variables in the Structure window in IntelliJ Community edition. Neither can I use functions such as "find references" etc. Is this even possible? I read that it should be? I got syntax highlighting to work but not anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find out on the [Web site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), JavaScript support is only available in IntelliJ Ultimate. Syntax highlighting is the only feature supported in Community Edition.